# Can I assign key strokes to KeyboardState?

Tags: c#, xna, keyboard, key

I capture pressed keys by following code:
`KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();`
Can I set key strokes to `keyState` so I can simulate user input?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.keyboardstate.keyboardstate.aspx)?

With `KeyboardState` constructor you can initialize a new instance of the `KeyboardState` class with an array or parameter list of `Keys` to initialize as pressed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Keys[] keys = new Keys[] {Keys.A, Keys.B}; 
KeyboardState keystate = new KeyboardState(keys); 
if (keystate.isKeyDown(Keys.A))
    //true
```

Try that, I'm not 100% sure that is what you want but it should be put you on the right track.